# JSP-form data is not entering mysql database

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, jdbc, netbeans

I have made an HTML file to design a registration page. On clicking Submit button, form values are sent to JSP page. But when I run this project, after filling the form, blank JSP page is displayed, not even "Failed to enter data" is displayed. And values are not entering into database. I am using Netbeans IDE. 
Here is the code for both files.

addlibform.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add Librarian</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <style>
        .label{
            font-size: 15px;
            color: black;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 500px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        .input{
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 650px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 style="position: absolute; margin-left: 550px;">Add Librarian</h1><br>
    <form method="post" action="addlib.jsp">
        <label for="username" class="label">Username:</label>

        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" required class="input"><br><br><br>

    <label for="password" class="label">Password:</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input"><br><br><br>

        <label for="address" class="label">Address:</label>

        <textarea rows="2" cols="22" name="add" class="input"></textarea><br><br><br>

        <label for="city" class="label">City:</label>

        <input type="text" name="city" class="input"><br><br><br>

        <label for="contact" class="label">Contact No.:</label>

        <input type="text" name="contact" class="input"><br><br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Librarian" style="position: relative; margin-left: 600px; margin-top: 100px;">
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Back" style="position: relative; margin-left: 600px; margin-top: 20px;">        
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

addlib.jsp file:

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="java.lang.*" %>
<%
String username = request.getParameter("userid");
String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
String add = request.getParameter("address");
String city = request.getParameter("city");
String contact = request.getParameter("contact");
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymgmt", "root", "root");
Statement st = c.createStatement();

int i=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO librarians VALUES('" + username + "','" + pwd + "','" + add + "','" + city + "','" + contact + ")");
if(i > 0)
    System.out.println("Librarian added successfully");
else
    System.out.println("Failed to insert data");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
"','" + contact + ")");
```

fails to close the single quote before closing the parenthesis.

That's your error.

But that's irrelevant.  Your problem here is not the particular error you made, but the fact that you are coding in the blind, without being able to see errors. If you continue coding in the blind, more errors will occur, and you will still not know what's wrong.  We at stackoverflow are here to help, but after a certain point it starts to get tedious, both for you and for us.

So, in your code, if an exception is thrown, (and as I explained above, it **is** thrown,) the `toString()` of the exception is output to the standard output. Do you see it in the console? If you unconditionally output "hello" to the standard output, (like, say, right before the `try{,`) do you see that?  If not, then that's the problem: errors are effectively suppressed, so you have no way of knowing what goes wrong.

How about ***NOT*** trying to catch the exception at all, so that the server will catch your exception for you and provide a meaningful error message both in the server log and on the actual web page?